# How can I sign in to a newly created Gmail account?

Tags: google-account, google-multi-login

I added a third Gmail account last night.

I am unable to log into it from another computer. If I go to gmail.com, it takes me to *https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox* (automatically logs me into one of my other accounts).

If I then click "Add Account" on the upper-right button or icon (with my image or avatar), it takes me to a page where I can "Choose an account," but it only has the two previous accounts listed, not the one I added last night (which is open and available on the original computer).

If I choose "Add an Account" again, there, it prompts me to sign in to to add another account, with the email address of the account currently open and a "Next" button. But nothing leads me to where I can select my new account.

I know it's possible to have multiple Gmail accounts simultaneously open, because I always have different ones open at work, and I now have the three at home simultaneously open.

So how can I find and open my third and newest account from a "foreign" machine (not the one on which the account was created)?

Comment: I'ts a bit unclear whether you want to sign-in to an account or keep multiple accounts open at the same time in the same browser. I have experience with the first only: logout of any accounts where you are currently signed-in, remove all accounts gmail offers you, add the new account. Or just dleete cookies/cache/history and restart the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I choose "Add an Account" again, there, it prompts me to sign in to
>   to add another account, with the email address of the account
>   currently open and a "Next" button. But nothing leads me to where I
>   can select my new account

On this page, there will be a link below the login box saying "Sign in as another user" or similar. That will take you to a page where you can login as the new user.

Comment: Okay, what I was missing was that when it prompted me to sign in, I was not changing the account name (from "old@gmail.com" to "new@gmail.com").